# branding settings error youtube api

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I have to update the featured video of my channel using youtube api.

When I sent PUT request using api explorer of the form

```
 PUT https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=brandingSettings&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

   {
     "brandingSettings": {
      "channel": {
        "featuredChannelsTitle": "featured channel",
        "featuredChannelsUrls": [
          "http://www.youtube.com/user/channelname"
         ]
        }
     },
     "id": "channelId"
   }
```

I am getting response as follows

```
   404 Not Found

   - Show headers -

   {
       "error": {
       "errors": [
       {
         "domain": "youtube.channel",
         "reason": "channelNotFound",
         "message": "Channel branding options not found.",
         "locationType": "parameter",
         "location": "id"
       }
     ],
    "code": 404,
   "message": "Channel branding options not found."
   }
  }
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong.

---

I was giving the wrong channel ID. But now I am trying with the correct Channel Id, and I am getting yet another error message.

```
Content-Type:  application/json
Authorization:  Bearer ya29.1.AADtN_X2UP_3BfFvUwAkvLp0d0mk1U-itJNVtWMPEJQU8G7INQ5q-UpI1yNMYniiLQ
X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer

 {
   "id": channelId,
   "brandingSettings": {
      "channel": {
        "featuredChannelsUrls": [
         " http://www.youtube.com/user/USERNAME"
        ],
       "featuredChannelsTitle": "Featured Channels"
      }
   }
 }
```

Response is 400 Bad Request

```
 - Show headers -

  {
    "error": {
      "errors": [
         {
            "domain": "youtube.channel",
            "reason": "brandingValidationError",
            "message": "Channel branding validation failed.",
            "locationType": "parameter",
            "location": "brandingSettings"
         }
      ],
     "code": 400,
     "message": "Channel branding validation failed."
   }
  }
```

If you can provide me a sample request it would be really helpful

Answer (score 1):

As it says in the error message, it couldn't find the channel, make sure you are giving the right channel id.

The way to do it in API, do a channels->list request and use that response object, modify it and put it back. (Most important make sure the id is there and set.)